# How to get value on class and put into array JavaScript DOM?

Tags: javascript

I have some tables that have data and can using it on `<td>`. So more like it I have something like this (show on images below)

**My Element**

[image]

I want to get that all positions Name and put it into an array so I can make of use that array I tried to use this code and got `undefined`

**script.js**

```
/** Checking if There positions name */
function checkPositions(){
   let positions = document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions').innerHTML;
   let array = [];
   array.push(positions);
   console.log(array);
}
```

Then how can I get that value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have is that `document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions')` returns a `HTMLCollection` which does not have an `innerHTML` property.

What you need to do is convert the `HTMLCollection` into an array, and then read the `innerHTML` property for each of the items in the array. See the following example:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions');
const positions = Array.from(elements).map(element => element.innerHTML);

console.log(positions);
```

```html
<div class="check-positions">1</div>
<div class="check-positions">2</div>
<div class="check-positions">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use like this**

```
   let positions = document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions')[0].innerHTML;
```

*It's showing none because u r fatching whole array and pushing it without using indexes*

**Code**

```
function checkPositions(){
       all_ele = document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions')
       length = all_ele.length
       let array = [];
       for( let i=0;i<length;i++)
       {
          let positions = document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions')[i].innerHTML;
          array.push(positions);
       }   
       console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery code to do this.

```
var arr = [];
$("#tablePlacement tr").each(function() {
var name =  $(this).children('td.check-positions').text();
arr.push(name);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
let positions = document.getElementsByClassName('check-positions').innerText;
```